# How many three-digit numbers can be generated from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, such that the digits are in ascending order?

Tags: combinatorics

Solution for the same is given below

Numbers starting with 12 – 7 numbers

Numbers starting with 13 – 6 numbers;

14 – 5, 15 – 4, 16 – 3, 17 – 2, 18 – 1.

Thus total number of

numbers starting from 1 is given by the sum of 1 to 7 = 28.

Number of numbers starting from 2- would be given by the sum of 1 to 6 = 21

Number of numbers starting from 3- sum of 1 to 5 = 15

Number of numbers starting from 4 – sum of 1 to 4 = 10

Number of numbers starting from 5 – sum of 1 to 3 = 6

Number of numbers starting from 6 = 1 + 2 = 3

Number of numbers starting from 7 = 1

Thus a total of: 28 + 21 + 15 + 10 + 6 + 3 + 1 = 84 such numbers.

suggest some trick to approach without thinking about this gibberish given above?

Comment: How many 3 digit numbers are possible? How many ways can a three digit number be put in one particular order? Divide.

Answer (score 3):

You need to choose three digits from nine.  Once the digits have been selected, the order in which they should be placed is determined.  Hence $\binom{9}{3}$ numbers are possible.

You are seeing binomial coefficients in your method too: once the first digit is fixed, there are $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to choose the remaining two digits, where $n$ is the number of digits greater than the first digit.  Equating our answers gives a binomial coefficient identity,
$$
\binom{9}{3}=\binom{8}{2}+\binom{7}{2}+\binom{6}{2}+\binom{5}{2}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{3}{2}+\binom{2}{2},
$$
which you can think about.

Comment: I would add that other instances of the binomial coefficient identity mentioned above occur repeatedly in your answer, e.g. $$28=\binom{8}{2}=\binom{7}{1}+\binom{6}{1}+\binom{5}{1}+\binom{4}{1}+\binom{3}{1}+\binom{2}{1}+\binom{1}{1}=7+6+5+4+3+2+1.$$  The general identity is $$\binom{n+1}{r+1}=\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n-1}{r}+\ldots+\binom{r}{r}.$$  It is sometimes called Hockey Stick Identity because the coefficients involved form a shape like a hockey stick in Pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick:

- An increasing arrangement must contain unique digits
- There are $\binom{9}{3}$ combinations of $3$ out of $9$ unique digits
- Each combination has exactly $1$ increasing arrangement
- Hence the number of increasing arrangements is $\binom{9}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

For each combination of 9 things taken 3 at a time, there is just 1 way they
can be arranged in ascending order.  So the answer is:

9C3 or C(9,3) = 84 ways

Comment: Use MathJax for math formatting-http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference